# Xamarin Form Error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, null, gesture-recognition

All day I was receiving this very clear (not the sarcasm) error message "*Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: type*"  I was hitting my head against the wall slowly decomposing my code until I could figure out the exact cause of the problem.  After much tedious deconstruction I discovered that I had an error in my `GestureRecognizers` section.  The problem was that I accidentally typed Command to try to pass a parameter instead of `CommandParameter`.

My original code generating the error looked like this.

```xml
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Value_Tapped" Command="language" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

The corrected code is this:

```xml
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Value_Tapped" CommandParameter="language" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears if you try to set the Command property to something Xamarin Forms does not know you will get this error.  If you get the error I suggest double checking all the non-intelisense correct parameters in your code.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix the issue after following every steps from [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/378848/#Comment_378848) post:

- Clean the solution.
- Close Visual Studio.
- Delete the `bin` and `obj` directories from each project in the solution (`YourProject`, `YourProject.Android`, `YourProject.iOS`)
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Build each project individually - NOT rebuild the solution.
- Rebuild Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but different issue.
I had a class with:

```
public int ID { get; set; } = 0;
public string PINLogin { get; set; } = "0";
public bool IsRecordable { get; set; } = false;
public string Picture{ get; set; } = "Picture";
public string Val1{ get; set; } = " ";
public string Val2{ get; set; } = " ";
```

After a few changes I removed `Val1` and `Val2`, but forgot to remove them from my `ListView` and that error was show.